# How sort order Shopify products by Product type in email template?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

How do we sort our product line items first by **Product type** then by **Product title**?

```
{% for line in line_items %}
```

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, so that the community knows what your already have worked on and can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort line items by title:

```
{%- assign line_items = line_items | sort: "title" -%}
```

You cannot sort items by type product type though.